# C++ portability from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, c++11, portability

I have been successfully using the following code in C++ on Windows (via CodeBlocks) and have recently attempted to use the same code on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) also via CodeBlocks. The code appears to compile fine but fails on execution.

The purpose of the code is to import a comma delimited text file of numbers into an array.

In both Windows and Linux I am using the GNU GCC Compiler.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

typedef vector <double> record_t;
typedef vector <record_t> data_t;

istream& operator >> ( istream& ins, record_t& record)
  {

  record.clear();

  string line;
  getline( ins, line );

  stringstream ss( line );
  string field;
  while (getline( ss, field, ',' ))
    {
    stringstream fs( field );
    double f = 0.0;  
    fs >> f;

    record.push_back( f );
    }

 return ins;
  }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

istream& operator >> ( istream& ins, data_t& data )
  {
  data.clear();

  record_t record;
  while (ins >> record)
    {
    data.push_back( record );
    }
return ins;
  }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
  {
  data_t data;

  ifstream infile( "Import File.txt" );
  infile >> data;

  if (!infile.eof())
    {
    cout << "Unsuccessful Import!\n";
    return 1;
   }

  infile.close();

  cout << "Your file contains " << data.size()-1 << " records.\n";

return 0;
  }
```

I've checked that the necessary header files exist on Linux and that appears to be the case.

If I comment out the EOF check the console returns the message that

```
Process returned 49 (0x31)
```

A snippet of the import file which fails under Linux is:

```
1138,1139,1137.25,1138.5
1138.25,1138.75,1138.25,1138.5
1138.75,1139,1138.5,1138.75
1138.75,1138.75,1138.25,1138.25
1138.25,1138.25,1137.5,1137.5
1137.5,1138.75,1137.5,1138.5
1138.75,1143.75,1138.75,1143
1143.25,1145.75,1143.25,1144.5
1144.5,1144.75,1143,1143.25
1143.5,1144.5,1143.25,1144.25
```

Grateful for any help in finding a solution.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of an input file for which the code is failing?

Comment: I have edited my question to include a snippet of the file which would work under Windows but not under Linux.

Answer (score 2):

That `return 4321;` in `main` reports an unsuccessful return code to the OS. Only `0` return code (aka `EXIT_SUCCESS`) is considered successful.

Change it to `return 0` or completely remove that `return` statement (in C++ `main` has implicit `return 0`).

Comment: Thanks. I've made the change but it doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @Jamesh99 I believe it solves the problem you reported, but your code has other problems. You may like to ask another question because SO is not a debugging service where you update your problems (as you do) as you get solutions to previous ones.